# Android Pull to Refresh on Webview gets stuck

Tags: android, webview, pull-to-refresh

I am beginner with Android development.

I have used https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh library for 'Pull to Refersh' feature.

I have configured web view for this feature and it's working fine.

The issue is when we pull to refresh, the web view gets stuck and i can not scroll the existing page.

Please help to resolve this issue or suggest alternate library for this feature.

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

There already exists a swipe down to refresh layout in the support library. Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Some samples:

- [SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic](http://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic/index.html)
- [SwipeRefreshListFragment](http://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshListFragment/index.html)
- [SwipeRefreshMultipleViews](http://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/index.html)